Can refinable strings managed properties be reused in other site collections independently?
I have used one of the RefinableString managed property in one site collection. And mapped it to a crawled property.
In the search schema on this site collection I can clearly see this mapping.
Whereas when I open another site collection and go to the search schema, then this same RefinableString managed property has no mapping. What is going on here? Does this mean I can reuse this same RefinableString managed property in other site collections without affecting the mappings in other site collections?
